# Why can't I delete my depot on Perforce?

Tags: perforce

I'm just messing around in a local Perforce database, trying to figure out how I can reset Perforce back to a previous state without journaling or deleting and recreating the database files.

I have some depots without files, one of them is called "sandbox". I created it with the `p4 depot` command either from the command line or using the P4Python API (at this point I don't remember which).

When I type:
`p4 depot -d sandbox` I get this:

> Depot sandbox isn't empty. To delete a depot, all file revisions must
>   be removed and all lazy copy references from other depots must be
>   severed. Use 'p4 obliterate' or 'p4 snap' to break file linkages from
>   other depots, then clear this depot with 'p4 obliterate', then retry
>   the deletion.

I tried `p4 obliterate -y //sandbox/...` which just says `No records to delete.` which is expectable as the depot is empty. Anyway it doesn't change the result from `p4 depot -d`. There are also no connections from other depots as the error message suggests.

Any idea what is happening and is there a foolproof way to force a depot to be deleted without deleting the server files altogether? Ultimately I want to do this automatically from P4Python.

EDIT: FWIW, here's the server log during the obliterate operation:

```
2012/04/11 09:30:18 pid 6916 username@machinename 127.0.0.1 [p4/2011.1/NTX86
/370818] 'user-obliterate -y //sandbox/...'
--- lapse .561s
--- rpc msgs/size in+out 0+1/0mb+0mb himarks 64836/64836
--- db.counters
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+436ms
--- db.user
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 1+0+0 0+0
--- db.group
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+1 0+0
--- db.domain
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+1
---   locks read/write 2/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 1+2+8 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+436ms/0ms+0ms
---   max lock wait+held read/write 0ms+436ms/0ms+0ms
--- db.view
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+1
---   locks read/write 2/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+2+6 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+436ms/0ms+0ms
---   max lock wait+held read/write 0ms+436ms/0ms+0ms
--- db.integed
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+1 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+390ms
--- db.resolve
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+343ms
--- db.have
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+1 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+296ms
--- db.label
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+249ms
--- db.locks
---   pages in+out+cached 3+0+2
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+1 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+171ms
--- db.archmap
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+1 0+0
--- db.rev
---   pages in+out+cached 4+0+2
---   locks read/write 1/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+2+2 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+16ms/0ms+171ms
--- db.revcx
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+140ms
--- db.revdx
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+93ms
--- db.revhx
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+62ms
--- db.revsx
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+46ms
--- db.working
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+31ms
--- db.traits
---   pages in+out+cached 4+3+2
---   locks read/write 0/1 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+0+0 0+0
---   total lock wait+held read/write 0ms+0ms/0ms+31ms
--- db.protect
---   pages in+out+cached 2+0+1
---   locks read/write 1/0 rows get+pos+scan put+del 0+1+1 0+0
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a force flag

```
p4 depot -f -d sandbox
```

as my depot folder contained a bunch of empty folders which weren't being deleted by obliterate.